# getRGB() returning different value after setRGB()

Tags: java, image-processing

I want to extract the pixel values from a jpeg image using getRGB(). But the problem is that the getRGB() method returns different values each time I invoke the method after setRGB(). After going through some solutions over the internet, many suggested to use .png images instead of .jpg. Now, is there a way to extract the pixel value ranging between 0-255 from a jpg image ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "But the problem is that the getRGB() method returns different values each time I invoke the method after setRGB()". What values do you set and what values are returned before and after you set the values?

Comment: Suppose I set the value as -4.336784 by setRGB() and it is returning -1.222234 by invoking getRGB()

Comment: I guess that you're doing something like `image.setRGB(x,y,rgb); int read = image.getRGB(x,y);` and then see that `rgb != read`, right? This is *very* likely due to the color model that is used internally. Try converting your image into an ARGB image, e.g. using the [`convertToARGB` method in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397515/3182664) , and see whether the problem goes away.

Comment: "between 0-255"  - You'll have to take the full value and bit-shift the byte components out I guess.